# How to import a sample DB into postgres?

Tags: postgresql

According to a [website](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-sample-database/) I can download their sample file `dvdrental.zip`, but

> The database file is in zipformat ( dvdrental.zip) so you need to extract > it to  dvdrental.tar

First of all, what is a tar?  I thought it had to be `tar.gz` to be compressed?  I don't even know how to create a "tar" by itself.  I tried:

`tar -zcvf dvdrental.tar.gz dvdrental`

and

`tar -cf dvdrental.tar dvdrental`

I try to import with pgAdmin 4 and I get either:

`pg_restore: [archiver] input file does not appear to be a valid archive`

or

`pg_restore: [tar archiver] could not find header for file "toc.dat" in tar archive`

respectively.  Now, don't ask me why a popular tutorial site created a file in the wrong format.  But, can you tell me how to repackage this file so I can use it as a sample DB?

Using Mac OS 10.12.4.  Postgres 9.6.  And PgAdmin 4 (not sure if it's in beta?  It crashed and does all kinds of nonsensical window movement and highlighting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into the `.tar` archive you will find the `restore.sql` where at the top:

```
-- File paths need to be edited. Search for $$PATH$$ and
-- replace it with the path to the directory containing
-- the extracted data files.
```

So to create sample DB you could to extract `.tar` content somewhere and use single command:

```
sed -e 's/\$\$PATH\$\$/\/path\/to\/extracted\/files/g' restore.sql | psql
```

Or

```
sed -e 's/\$\$PATH\$\$/\/path\/to\/extracted\/files/g' restore.sql > r.sql
```

and try to execute the `r.sql` content using PgAdmin.

Answer (score 3):

I have extracted .zip archive first. Then opened pgAdmin and followed the guide "Load the DVD Rental database using the pgAdmin"

https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/load-postgresql-sample-database/

Pay attention to changing 'Format' field from 'Custom or Tar' to 'Directory'. Then you should be able to restore DB.

Comment: holy heck, this simple answer just solved 2 hours of hunting

Answer (score 1):

get sample dataset from the link you cited and save somewhere.
Assuming postgres is installed and running do the following:

Run `createdb dvdrental`

Run `pg_restore -d dvdrental ./dvdrental` where "./dvdrental" is the path to the downloaded and unzipped file.

Answer (score 0):

**For create sample DB in postgres you following this steps:**

1.- Create directory and enter it:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/dvdrental && cd /tmp/dvdrental
```

2.- Download zip file dvdrental.zip:

```
wget https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/dvdrental.zip
```

3.- Uncompress file .zip and later .tar:

```
unzip dvdrental.zip

tar -xvf dvdrental.tar
```

4.- Replace in execution time **$$PATH** variable and review it with **grep** command:

```
sed -e 's/\$\$PATH\$\$/\/tmp\/dvdrental/g' restore.sql  | grep --color dvdrental
```

5.- Import DB sample for specific host (**localhost**), port (**5433**), user (**db**) and database name (**postgres**):

```
sed -e 's/\$\$PATH\$\$/\/tmp\/dvdrental/g' restore.sql  | psql -h localhost -p 5433 -U db -d postgres
```

Finally, I show import successful with program pgAdmin III
[image: I show import successful with program pgAdmin III]